# Confusion with templates in django

Tags: django

I was learning django and I have the following template:

```
{% load static ax_base %}
{% for tm in team_list %}
<div>

    <div class="card our-team-slider-card mb-3">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="" class="card-img-wrap" data-toggle="modal"
                   data-target=".our-team-photo">
                    <img src="{% static tm.img %}"
                         class="card-img" alt="...">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title mb-4">{{ tm.name }}</h5>
                    <div class="profession mb-4 fz14 opa05">{{ tm.position }}</div>
                    <p class="card-text fz14 opa05">{{ tm.bio }}</p>
                    <div class="contacts mb-2">
                        <a href=""
                           class="styled-link text-black">{{ tm.phone }}</a><span> , </span><a
                            href="" class="styled-link text-black">{{ tm.email }}</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="" class="styled-link text-primary">Send message</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

So, the problem is I have two places where the above template is reused but what I want to do is to use col-sm-4 class in one place but not use col-sm-4 in the other place. Should I create two separate templates for that, that is, one template that uses col-sm-4 and the other template that does not use col-sm-4? Would that be correct?

Comment: the best probably would be to pass to context `bool` variable like `hide = True` and wrap you class inside if statement inside template

Comment: @AlexanderLekontsev, pls can you create an answer with the necessary code)))?

Comment: pass hide variable from your view

Comment: now check i think my answer will answer your question

Comment: @AlexanderLekontsev, sorry Alex, I only need to use conditionals for class="col-sm-4", that is, if I pass hide variable then class="col-sm-4 should NOT be used. And if I do not pass hide variable then use class="col-sm-4". Is that possible to achive that?

Comment: Yes, just wrap your class in if statement, not entire block

Comment: @AlexanderLekontsev, sorry Alexander, I am using the above template like this {% team_menu %} sorry but how can I pass hide variable in here?

Comment: If you're using it inside another template, pass to variable to parent template

Answer (score 1):

```
{% load static ax_base %}
{% for tm in team_list %}
<div>

    <div class="card our-team-slider-card mb-3">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            {% if not hide %}
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="" class="card-img-wrap" data-toggle="modal"
                   data-target=".our-team-photo">
                    <img src="{% static tm.img %}"
                         class="card-img" alt="...">
                </a>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title mb-4">{{ tm.name }}</h5>
                    <div class="profession mb-4 fz14 opa05">{{ tm.position }}</div>
                    <p class="card-text fz14 opa05">{{ tm.bio }}</p>
                    <div class="contacts mb-2">
                        <a href=""
                           class="styled-link text-black">{{ tm.phone }}</a><span> , </span><a
                            href="" class="styled-link text-black">{{ tm.email }}</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="" class="styled-link text-primary">Send message</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your were wrong when you passed the image with `{% static tm.img %}` better change it to `{{ tm.img }}`

```
{% load static ax_base %}
{% for tm in team_list %}
<div>

    <div class="card our-team-slider-card mb-3">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="" class="card-img-wrap" data-toggle="modal"
                   data-target=".our-team-photo">
                    <img src="{{ tm.img }}"
                         class="card-img" alt="...">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title mb-4">{{ tm.name }}</h5>
                    <div class="profession mb-4 fz14 opa05">{{ tm.position }}</div>
                    <p class="card-text fz14 opa05">{{ tm.bio }}</p>
                    <div class="contacts mb-2">
                        <a href=""
                           class="styled-link text-black">{{ tm.phone }}</a><span> , </span><a>
                            href="" class="styled-link text-black">{{ tm.email }}</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="" class="styled-link text-primary">Send message</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just pass a variable in render context dict and use that for the conditionally shown block:

```
{% if show_photo %}
<div class="col-sm-4">
...
</div>
{% endif %}
```

If it is the actual class you want or don't want to use, it can also be handled in exactly same syntax:

```
<div class="{% if use_sm_4 %} col-sm-4 {% else %} some-other-class {% endif %}">
...
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but how can I pass variable, that is, I am using the template like this {% team_menu %} and how can I pass use_sm_4 variable?

Comment: pls I really need your help(((

Comment: You pass it to the renderer in the view. You can provide extra vars in the context dict as you like and use those in the template. For example check out render(): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render
Or if you are using class based views, just override the get_context_data like here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context